# Fullscreen images in specific div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just try to make fullscreen images in specific div on click, a div of my choix.
Not all images on DOM but just all images in a specific di .

I wrote a js file that create img TAG  `<img >` and join a src of my images in this img TAG.
attach the tour to my div tag which has the id pano2

Now i want to fullscreen  only these images  on click ( only images i joined in my div tag which has the id pano2
)
I'm limited about js skill;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+OR+jQuery+click+div+fullscreen+image+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.